# Nested Scss @each with variables

Tags: html, css, function, sass

Is it possible to create a function inside a nested variable with scss/sass?
I was using this article to help guide me but I did not find anything on whether it would work inside a nested color variable.
[Article *working-with-lists-and-each-loops-in-sass-with-the-index-and-nth-function*](https://benfrain.com/working-with-lists-and-each-loops-in-sass-with-the-index-and-nth-function/)

I want to create a function to automate the creation of these variables

```
$oranges:   #af5422;
$oranges2:  #FFCA28;
$oranges3:  #FFA000;

$fish: (
  orange: (
   "goldfish-1": $oranges,
   "goldfish-2": $oranges2,
   "goldfish-3": $oranges3,
  )
) !default;

h1 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-1");
}
h2 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-2");
}
h3 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-3");
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaJrBN)

I am looking to do something like this but I can't figure it out.

```
$oranges: #af5422 #FFCA28 #FFA000;

$fish: (
  orange: 
    @each $current-color in $oranges {
        $i: index($oranges, $current-color);
        "goldfish-#{$i}": $current-color,
    }
  )
) !default;

h1 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-1");
}
h2 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-2");
}
h3 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-3");
}
```

[codepen 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpgqov)

Is it even possible or is there a similar way to execute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to loop inside a `map`

However this is how you can achieve what you want easily. I am using the **sass** syntax

```
$oranges: #af5422 #FFCA28 #FFA000
$orange: ()

@each $current-colour in $oranges
  $i: index($oranges, $current-colour)
  $orange: map-merge($orange, ("goldfish-#{$i}": $current-colour))

$fish: (orange: $orange) !default

h1
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-1")

h2 
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-2")

h3 
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-3")
```

This is the **scss** syntax

```
$oranges: #af5422 #FFCA28 #FFA000;
$orange: ();

@each $current-colour in $oranges {
  $i: index($oranges, $current-colour);
  $orange: map-merge($orange, ("goldfish-#{$i}": $current-colour));
}

$fish: (orange: $orange) !default;

h1 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-1");
}

h2 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-2");
}

h3 {
  color: map-get(map-get($fish, orange), "goldfish-3");
}
```

They both compile to the following css

```
h1 {
  color: #af5422; }

h2 {
  color: #FFCA28; }

h3 {
  color: #FFA000; }
```

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR EXTENSION**

Based on what you want to achieve in the link in your comment
This is the code using **sass** indented style

```
$oranges: #af5422 #FFCA28 #FFA000
$newvar: car plane truck

$shaded: 5% 15%
$orange: ()
$vehicle: ()

@each $current-colour in $oranges
  $i: index($oranges, $current-colour)
  $orange: map-merge($orange, ($i*100:$current-colour))

$fish: ( orange: $orange) !default

@each $automobile in $newvar
  $i: index($newvar, $automobile)
  @for $count from 1 through 5
    $new_map: ()
    @if $count == 1
      $new_map: map-merge($new_map, ($count *100: lighten(nth($oranges, $i), nth($shaded, 2))))
    @else if $count == 2
      $new_map: map-merge($new_map, ($count *100: lighten(nth($oranges, $i), nth($shaded, 1))))
    @else if $count == 3
      $new_map: map-merge($new_map, ($count *100: nth($oranges, $i)))
    @else
      $new_map: map-merge($new_map, ($count *100: darken(nth($oranges, $i), nth($shaded, 1))))
    $vehicle: map-merge($vehicle, $new-map)
  $fish: map-merge($fish, ($automobile: $vehicle))
```

Comment: hmm alright thanks, i really wanted to be able to automate the maps to keep everything organized, i will give this a try to see if I can come up with a similar solution.

Comment: This is automated because the`each` loop dynamically creates the `maps`. All you need to do is add colours to the `$oranges` variable. If you are worried about your code not being organised, you could create a `partial` file for `variables` and import that file in your main sass file. This is actually common practice. Hope this helps :)

Comment: how can I extend this a bit further and add an extra step to change the name of "orange" and also add the lighten and darken feature? I've been messing with it for the past 6 hours and can't even come close. [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjxwrZ)

Comment: The code looks less than pretty. The logic behind the `$shaded` list and using it to manipulate the `$oranges` colour is interesting so there wasn't much for me to work without fully understanding how you came up with what you want to achieve and the reason. Some slight recommendations would be to work on your `variable naming` conventions and extract the `map creation` to a `function`. That way there might not be so much code in the loop. And why are the last two colours ie for `400` and `500` ALWAYS the same for each `vehicle`? It makes me wonder is the `$shaded` list even necessary?

Comment: thanks, i tried to make the code prettier and proposed a new question here. [stack new question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135762/scss-map-merge-functions)  Not sure if it is possible to achieve what I want but I will keep playing with it. The $shaded values are 5% and 15% because I want the color to be shaded light 5% and 15%. I also want the darken to be 5% and 15%. In total each color would have 5 different options. The normal one and two above/two below.

Comment: I achieved what you wanted though, I used the different shades for the map. You can use `@debug $fish` to see the value. But there are only four different options because you said `darken 5%` for both `400` and `500` according to the comment in the link. But the code outputs what you want it to. The main problem is that you want to iterate using `2 shades` to get `5 colours` for `3 items`. Like I said earlier, I think the logic just need to be broken down. I'll try to have another look at it during my spare time.

Comment: yeah the 5% was a error. I meant to put 5 and 15 for 400 and 500. yeah, sure that would be awesome. I am trying to learn how to make more advanced maps but this one has really gotten me stumped.