# SCSS map-merge functions

Tags: html, css, function, sass

Hello I am trying to make a more advanced map-merge function. Currently I only have the colors inside the "red: ( );"

[full example on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALmLLA)

```
$red:   #f00;
$green: #0f0;
$blue:  #00f;
$colours: $red $green $blue;
$output: ();

@each $current-colour in $colours {
   $i: index($colours, $current-colour);
   $output: map-merge($output, ($i*100:$current-colour));
}

$rgbcolors (
     red: ( 
         //only this is being generated with the code
         100: $red,
         200: $green,
         300: $blue
     )
 ) !default;
```

I want to be able to generate the code inside the map.

```
$rgbcolors (
     // I want to generate the code here So instead of applying the values inside the map I can make the "green" and the "blue" map headers and also create the values inside it
     red: ( 
         100: $red,
         200: $red,
         300: $red
     ),
     green: ( 
         100: $green,
         200: $green,
         300: $green
     ),
     blue: ( 
         100: $blue,
         200: $blue,
         300: $blue
     )
 ) !default;
```

Then to take it a step further I want to lighten and darken the first and third values.

```
......
green: ( 
    100: lighten($green, 5%),
    200: $green,
    300: darken($green, 5%)
 ),
.....
```

Would I need a @for and and @each to make this work?

Comment: Why use map to do this? I think is too complicated your code and very confused call colors with `map-get(map-get($rgbcolors, red), 100)`. Maybe you have a good reason to do that way but you can get the same and more reusable with simple mixin: [sassmeister demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/01e3270c1be3efaf13f56da0c32ac9eb)

Comment: @blonfu my end goal was to just be able to input lets say 10 colors and it creates 9 different values for each color. So for $red it would lighten it 4 times and darken it 4 times. It would also create the map as well. this is an example of how i want the colors to come out but i wanted it to be a function/for loop or something that would automate the creation [link to demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGxrKQ) then in i could call a color simply by doing "color: getColor(red, 100)"  or "color: getColor(orange, 700)"